# SDK installation cmd error: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, cmd, sdk

I am stuck in cmd as I enter the line below. Please help, and thank you!

Line input:`"$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

Error output: `'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The link referred: https://sdkman.io/install

Comment: Ignoring the fact that it clearly says so, right at the top of your linked page, are you aware that the code you've supplied is from a Unix Shell Script, _(`.sh`)_, not a Windows Command Script, _(`.cmd`)_. Unless you've installed WSL[2] or a dedicated Unix environment you'll need to convert/rewrite the shell script as a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
Error output: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external 
command, operable program or batch file.
```

comes from a Windows command shell.  But instructions you are following are for Linux.  You need to read the instructions for Windows ... which are further down the page.